# How to remove the dotted line in the image map in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code:

```
<img alt="Testing 2015" border="0" src="images/Test-2015.jpg" usemap="#Map" />

<p><map name="Map"><area coords="790,100,653,135" href="http://www.google.com/" shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_blank" /></map></p>
```

When I'm clicking on that image, getting dotted line.

Anyone can help me out for this?

Comment: My eyes may be deceiving me, but I don't see any code.

Comment: You forgot to add code, Pl add it first

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/2cpqmrob/  i dont see any dotted line

Comment: Links get a dotted link when they are focused...

Comment: Yup, there is a dotted line: http://jsfiddle.net/2cpqmrob/2/

Answer (score 1):

Add onfocus="blur();" to the following code section will solve the problem:

```html
   <img alt="Testing 2015" border="0" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/d/de/140_WHITE_on_WHITE_S.png" usemap="#Map" width='200'/>

<p><map name="Map"><area coords="0,0,200,100" onfocus="blur();" href="javascript:return false;" shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer;" target="_blank" /></map></p>
```